# Adding several features to someone's GitHub repo while having all the latest commits available locally?

Tags: git, github, branch

As the title indicates, I would like to add several independent features to someone else's project as separate pull requests. At the same time, I would like to use the program with all of these new features on my own local branch, without having to wait for the original author to merge them.

This is my current workflow:

1. Fork
2. Clone locally
3. Create new branches
4. Develop features, one per branch
5. Push commits to new branches on my GitHub fork
6. Create separate pull requests from these branches to the original author's repo.

I am not sure what to do after this, there are a few alternatives to choose from:

7a. Merge branches locally, but not remotely?

7b. Merge branches locally and push to the master branch of my fork before the original author has accepted the individual pull requests (Would this impact the pending pull requests somehow)?

7c. Don't merge anything, just make all the features available in my working tree and then discard when they are officially merged upstream?

Which of these options (or some option I didn't think of) would be the more correct last step? I would prefer 7b as long as it does not impact the pending pull requests. Is there something else in the workflow that I could benefit from changing as well?

Comment: On your local repo, for your own amusement, you can do whatever you feel like. You could start a new branch called my-next from origin/master and merge all your feature branches and have fun there. If upstream adds more stuff into origin/master you can easily merge them into my-next. If you would like to start over then delete my-next and start over.

Comment: I would merge them into my own local master branch, or branch off of master and then merge the features into that new branch.

Comment: @Edmundo Thanks, is it advised not to push this branch to my fork on GitHub, but keep it local until the pending pull requests are resolved?

Comment: Your fork on git-hub is also yours so feel free to post there whatever you feel like _others_ would perhaps like to see or play with. That's what I think of when I post something on my own github repos.

Comment: Thanks @Edmundo, just to clarify, if I push the changes into my Github master branch, will the pending pull requests from those branches be left untouched? I guess there will be troubles if there are changes requested to those pull requests, since I would not have the branches anymore? Or could I just pull the pull requested branch from the upstream repo now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think pushing to master would affect the pending pull requests. Pull requests are associated to given revisions (I assume, just in case) and they would be untouched if you pushed into another branch (even if the pull requests are based originally from the branch you are trying to push into).

Comment: Could you clarify that last part? When I someone requests changes to my pull request, I will push those to the same branch on my repository as the pull request originated from, which I think is inconsistent with what you wrote in the last parenthesis (or I'm misunderstanding you).

Comment: I don´t think it´s confusing but here it goes explained: You create a branch called feature-X locally from origin/master. You do your commits, push into your own github repo. Then you create a pull request on the project repo. In the mean time, 2 other people have been adding stuff into origin/master. The pull request history is not tied to origin/master as it _is_ right now but as it _was_ before, no matter what happens with origin/master after you started feature-X.